# High iteration Newton's Method

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

> Suppose newton's iteration method is applied to $f(x)=1/x$ with $x_{0}=1$. Find $x_{50}$.

So for me it seems like that newton's method is trying to approximate the root of the function.

From Newton's Method

$x_{i+1}=x_{i}-\frac{f(x_{i})}{f'(x_{i})}$

So

\begin{align*}
x_{i+1}=x_{i}-\frac{\frac{1}{x_{i}}}{-\frac{1}{x^2_{i}}}=x_{i}+x_{i}
\end{align*}
From the above relation, we can compute the first values
\begin{align*}
x_{1}&=x_{0}+x_{0}=2\\
x_{2}&=x_{1}+x_{1}=4\\
x_{3}&=x_{2}+x_{2}=8\\
x_{4}&=x_{3}+x_{3}=16\\
x_{5}&=x_{4}+x_{4}=32
\end{align*}
So
\begin{align*}
x_{0}&=1\\
x_{1}&=x_{0} \cdot 2\\
x_{2}&=x_{0} \cdot 2^2\\
x_{3}&=x_{0} \cdot 2^3\\
x_{n}&=x_{0} \cdot 2^n
\end{align*}

Therefore

$x_{50}=2^{50}$
I just think my result looks strange, does it just mean what we can see intuitively that the function has no roots?

Comment: In this case, it's the consequence of the function having a monotonic decrease to an asymptote, so yes. You can see this intuitively if you recall that the Newton's method is tracing the tangent to the x axis intercept. But in general, even if a function has roots, Newton's iteration depends on initial condition, and may converge to different values or not at all. See Newton's fractals to see how complex this behaviour can be.

Comment: Thank you, I am not sure if we have coevered newton's fractals in my numerical course. Would you say that my answer is sufficient if I say that the function diverges as we can see the function tends towards infinity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is correct, $x_n = 2^n x_0$.

The case of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ if a good example of what can go wrong. There is no root to find as $f(x) \not = 0$ for all $x \not =0$. The absolute value of the residual, i.e., $|f(x_n)|$, converges to zero, while $|x_n| \rightarrow \infty$. If the residual is used to terminate the iteration, then the user will be given the wrong impression, i.e., a root has been found. The morale is two-fold 1) do not feed your software a problem which cannot be solved, 2) always look at the intermediate results.

A good implementation of Newton's method will not rely on Newton's method alone. It will accept a bracket, i.e. an interval $[a,b]$ such that $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs and $f : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous. It will systematically shrink the bracket using a combination of Newton's method and bisection.

---

EDIT: In response to OP's comment.

A formal proof of the fact that $x_n = 2^n x_0$ can be done as follows. Let $V \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be given by
$$ V = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} \: : x_n = 2^n x_0\}.$$
We must show that $1 \in V$ and if $k \in V$, then $k+1 \in V$.

It has already been established that $$x_{n+1} = 2 x_n, \quad  n=0,1,2\dotsc.$$ In particular, $$x_1 = 2 x_0 = 2^1 x_0,$$ or equivalently, $1 \in V$.

Now suppose that $k \in V$. We must show that $k+1 \in V$, i.e., $x_{k+1} = 2^{k+1} x_0$. By assumption, $x_k = 2^{k} x_0$. Therefore, $$x_{k+1} = 2 x_k = 2 (2^k x_0) = 2^{k+1} x_0.$$ We conclude that $k+1 \in V$.

By the principle of mathematical induction, we can now conclude that $V = \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Depending on the situation, such formalism is overkill. However, it is good practice to write clearly about simple matters. How else can one learn to write clearly about complicated matters?

Comment: thanks, would one have to show that $x_{n}=2^{n}x_{0}$ by induction?

Comment: @Djhoe Yes, induction is the natural choice in this case. I added a paragraph on this issue.

Comment: Thank you, I always had a little trouble with induction, but it seems like a good practice indeed thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider the point at which the function $f(x)=0$. It's impossible for this to be true. In fact:
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}{\frac{1}{x}}=\infty$$
In short, what you are attempting to do is find some $x$ such that $f(x)=0$, and each time you perform the iterative again you will get closer to the root, which you can see as your 
$$\lim_{i\to \infty}{x_i}=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

It is correct as root of 1/x is infinity
Sometimes the newtons method gives weird results when the root is a complex number but it gives correct answer in most of the cases

Comment: Here the root isn't a complex number either; it just doesn't exist.

Comment: I was just telling for fact and not for this case and here the root is infinity by definition