# Checking to see if is correct

Tags: numerical-methods

Suppose Newton’s method is applied to the function f(x) = 1/x. If the initial guess is
x0 = 1, find x50.

Solution
F(x) =1/x        x0=1 where n=1,2,3,...
F'(x) =-1/(x^2)
Xn+1=xn-(f(xn))/(f'(xn))
And I had x50=1125899907*10^6

Comment: Your answer makes sense, considering that $f(x) = 1/x$ has no zeros.

Comment: Boy... this is the worst posting title I have *ever* seen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [High iteration Newton's Method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755867/high-iteration-newtons-method)

Comment: You may find [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2755901/307944) answer to your question instructive.

Answer (score 1):

I get that
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} = x_n - \frac{\frac{1}{x_n}}{-\frac{1}{x_n^2}} = x_n + x_n = 2x_n,$$
thus $x_n = 2^n$, given $x_0 = 1$. According to Google, we have
$$x_{50} = 2^{50} \approx 1.1258999 \cdot 10^{15},$$
which appears roughly the same as what you've got.